# Need help connecting "C" wire, unknown red and white wire from one unit to the other

Tags: hvac

We are replacing our old thermostats (installed in 2006) with two smart thermostats. We have 2 separate units and thermostats. We have an unused blue wire (c wire) at both thermostats. We thought we could just connect those on the control panel in the attic and we'd be all set. However my 2 units are connected in the attic by a red wire that runs from the "C" on control panel of one unit to the "C" on the control panel of the 2nd unit, and a white wire that runs between the 2 "Y"'s. What is this, and can you advise how to connect the c (blue) wires at the control panel in this situation? I have attached photos. Note that we connected this blue wire on the units just now (anticipating the "C" connection may be able to be shared), but have not yet connected it on the thermostat end.[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: It sounds like the two units in the attic have been set up so that they both come on when there is a call for heat.  Is there a single heat system that both air handlers need to control?

Comment: The heat on each side of house operates independently.

Comment: What make and model is this "control panel" of yours?

Comment: I have revised my question to include more information and correct the white wiring, it goes to "Y". Thank you

Comment: How is the air conditioning compressor (outdoor unit) wired to all this?

Comment: 2 outside compressors, connections run through attic.

Comment: I have added a wiring diagram if that helps.